# How to stop Firefox opening new tabs for file links?

Tags: linux, firefox, browser-tabs

This behaviour only started happening in the past week or so, I have Firefox configured to handle ssh:// links, which has worked well for some months, but suddenly these links are opening blank new tabs and leaving them there even though the link is otherwise handled properly.

This issue has nothing to do with the script itself, assigning anything else (or nothing) to handle ssh:// links still generates these trash tabs. Is there a setting somewhere under the hood to say "Don't open a new tab for file links"?

On Fedora, Firefox-90.0-3.fc34.x86_64, issue has been present since at least Firefox 89.0.2-2.fc34.

Comment: Firefox-90 : Have you tried "un-tick" *Open links in tabs instead of new windows* ? ...... Settings → General

Comment: @KnudLarsen Tested this now, it happens to open an empty garbage window, instead of a tab.

Comment: Firefox 90.0-3 : I checked one of my Fedora 34 installs: **a**. KDE - plasma - X11, and **b**. Mate - Desktop . .... No issues, a new "Firefox window" opens perfectly. ....... Your error: Could it be a "Gnome3 integration" issue ? ( I never use Gnome 3 , any OS.)